# position a child sprite to the same position as the parent?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite which also has a child sprite.  I am trying to understand how to properly set the child sprite's position so that it matches the same screen position as the parent.  I thought based off of reading the docs, that I should just be able to do:

```
child.position = [child convertToNodeSpaceAR:parent.position];
```

however, that does not give the correct position.

I know I can do:

```
child.position = ccp(parent.textureRect.size.width * parent.anchorPoint.x,
                     parent.textureRect.size.height * parent.anchorPoint.y);
```

but I thought the convertToXXSpace methods were supposed handle this as a convenience?

Comment: use the non-AR version of the method. Also if the child is a direct child of the parent it suffices to set child position to 0,0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
child.position = [parent convertToNodeSpace:parent.position];
```

You want to take a position and convert it to the parent's coordinate space, which is why you call this on the parent class.

**Edited:**

On second thought you have a child attached to a parent and you want the child's position to match the same position as the parent. To do this try adding the child to the parent and using a position of (0,0) for the child:

```
[parent addChild:child];
child.position = CGPointZero;
```

Technically you should not have to touch the child's position afterwards. If you move the parent the child will automatically move with it. The only time you will change the child is if you are offsetting it from its parent, which based on your OP you are not.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have a child attached to a parent you don't have to ever change the child's position. Just move the parent and it moves along with it.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.  I realize the child moves with the parent, but I am trying to position the child to the exact position of parent.  position(0,0) is the lower left corner of the parent.  The parent's anchor point varies based off of logic in the game, and so I want a sure way for the child to be exactly in the same screen position as the parent.